# Proper transformation setup for scale and then rotation

Tags: graphics, opengl-es, matrix, webgl

My matrix math is a bit rusty, so I'm having some trouble figuring out the proper transformation process that I need to apply here.

I have a full-screen quad with coordinates ranging from `[-1, 1]` in both directions. I texture this quad with a non-square texture and then scale my modelview matrix to resize and preserve the aspect ratio. I want to also rotate the resized quad, but I'm getting stretched/distorted results.

Here's the process that I'm going through:

```
_gl.viewport(0, 0, _gl.viewportWidth, _gl.viewportHeight); // full-screen viewport
mat4.rotate(_modelview_matrix, degToRad(-1.0 * _desired_rotation), [0, 0, 1]); // rotate around z
mat4.scale(_modelview_matrix, [_shape.width / _gl.viewportWidth, _shape.height / _gl.viewportHeight, 1]); // scale down
```

Note that this is implemented in WebGL, but the process should be universal.

For simplicity's sake, this is all being done at the origin. I'm pretty sure I'm missing some relationship between the scaling down and the rotation, but I'm not sure what it is.

[image: Rotation distortion]

If I want the size of the quad to be `_shape.width, _shape.height` and have a rotation by an arbitrary angle, what am I missing?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use arbitrary combinations of projection and modelview. So just make your life easy: Use some projection that retains the windows aspect ratio, so that modelview coordinates don't get anisotropically distorted. Then just draw the texture onto a quad with the same edge ratio.

This is in C, but the concept should be transferrable easy enough.

```
typedef struct Projection {
    enum{perspective, ortho} type;
    union {
        GLfloat fov;
        GLfloat size;
    };
    GLfloat near;
    GLfloat far;
} Projection;

Projection projection;

GLuint tex_width;
GLuint tex_height;

GLuint viewport_width;
GLuint viewport_height;

/*...*/

void display()
{
    GLfloat viewport_aspect;

    if(!viewport_width || !viewport_height)
        return;

    viewport_aspect = (float)viewport_width/(float)viewport_height;

    glViewport(0, 0, viewport_width, viewport_height);

    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glLoadIdentity();

    switch(projection.type) {
    case ortho: {
            glOrtho(-0.5 * viewport_aspect * projection.size, 
                     0.5 * viewport_aspect * projection.size, 
                    -0.5 * projection.size,
                     0.5 * projection.size,
                    -projection.near,
                     projection.far );
        }
    case perspective: {
            glFrustum( -0.5 * viewport_aspect * projection.near * projection.fov, 
                        0.5 * viewport_aspect * projection.near * projection.fov, 
                       -0.5 * projection.near * projection.fov,
                        0.5 * projection.near * projection.fov,
                       -projection.near,
                        projection.far );
        }
    default:
        return;
    }

    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
    glLoadIdentity();

    {
        GLfloat const T = 0.5*(float)texture_width/(float)texture_height;

        GLfloat quad[4][4] = {
           /* X     Y,   U,     V */
            {-T, -0.5,  0.0,  0.0},
            { T, -0.5,  1.0,  0.0},
            { T,  0.5,  1.0,  1.0},
            {-T,  0.5,  0.0,  1.0},
        }

        glEnableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
        glEnableClientState(GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY);
        glVertexPointer(2, GL_FLOAT, (char*)&quad[6]-(char*)&quad[2], &quad[2]);
        glTexCoordPointer(2, GL_FLOAT, (char*)&quad[6]-(char*)&quad[2], &quad[2]);

        glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
        glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture_ID);

        glDrawArrays(GL_QUADS, 0, 4);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! This was exactly what I needed. I went back and adjusted the position of my vertices using your example as a guide. That was the separation I needed between the scaling and the aspect ratio preservation.

Answer (score 2):

I've never used webgl, so no example from me here, but you should never do aspect ratio correction in your modelview matrix. That's something for the projection matrix to do.

An example on how to do it can be found [here](http://www.khronos.org/webgl/wiki/Tutorial#Setting_Up_the_Viewport).

Comment: Oops! Thanks for pointing out my mistake in trying to merge the modelview and projection matrices together. I *think* in this isolated case it didn't make a difference because I was only performing two transformations, but it's still terribly bad practice. I've fixed this in my code now.